# How to use back button with div

Tags: jquery, jsp

As suggested the changes in my previous question i changed my entire code using div command. My source code is as follows:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>
</TITLE>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</HEAD>

<BODY>
<H1></H1>
<script language="JavaScript">
function NextData(ctrr)

{
 switch (ctrr) {
    case 1:
        $("a").hide();
        $("INPUT").hide();


        $('#myDiv').append('<table><tr><td>');
        $('#myDiv').append('<A HREF ="javascript:Data(1)">Spotlight</A>');
        $('#myDiv').append('</td></tr></table>');

        $('#myDiv').append('<table><tr><td>');
        $('#myDiv').append('<A HREF ="javascript:Data(2)">Simply the Best</A>');
        $('#myDiv').append('</td></tr></table>');

        $('#myDiv').append('<table><tr><td>');
        $('#myDiv').append('<A HREF ="javascript:Data(3)">Juke box</A>');
        $('#myDiv').append('</td></tr></table>');

        $('#myDiv').append('<table><tr><td>');
        $('#myDiv').append('<A HREF ="javascript:Data(4)">100 Greatest Album/Single</A>');
        $('#myDiv').append('</td></tr></table>');

        $('#myDiv').append('<table><tr><td>');
        $('#myDiv').append('<A HREF ="javascript:Data(5)">List All Artists</A>');
        $('#myDiv').append('</td></tr></table>');

        $('#myDiv').append('<table><tr><td>');
        $('#myDiv').append('<A HREF ="javascript:Data(6)">List All Albums</A>');
        $('#myDiv').append('</td></tr></table>');

        $('#myDiv').append('<table><tr><td>');
        $('#myDiv').append('<A HREF ="javascript:Data(7)">Arabic</A>');
        $('#myDiv').append('</td></tr></table>');

        $('#myDiv').append('<table><tr><td>');
        $('#myDiv').append('<A HREF ="javascript:Data(8)">Hindi</A>');
        $('#myDiv').append('</td></tr></table>');

        $('#myDiv').append('<table><tr><td>');
        $('#myDiv').append('<A HREF ="javascript:Data(9)">Pop</A>');
        $('#myDiv').append('</td></tr></table>');

        $('#myDiv').append('<table><tr><td>');
        $('#myDiv').append('<A HREF ="javascript:Data(10)">Rock</A>');
        $('#myDiv').append('</td></tr></table>');

        $('#myDiv').append('<table><tr><td>');
        $('#myDiv').append('<A HREF ="javascript:Data(11)">Jazz & Blues</A>');
        $('#myDiv').append('</td></tr></table>');

        $('#myDiv').append('<table><tr><td>');
        $('#myDiv').append('<A HREF ="javascript:Data(12)">Country</A>');
        $('#myDiv').append('</td></tr></table>');

        $('#myDiv').append('<table><tr><td>');
        $('#myDiv').append('<A HREF ="javascript:Data(13)">Classical</A>');
        $('#myDiv').append('</td></tr></table>');

        $('#myDiv').append('<table><tr><td>');
        $('#myDiv').append('<A HREF ="javascript:Data(14)">Dance</A>');
        $('#myDiv').append('</td></tr></table>');

        $('#myDiv').append('<table><tr><td>');
        $('#myDiv').append('<A HREF ="javascript:Data(15)">Easy Listening</A>');
        $('#myDiv').append('</td></tr></table>');

        $('#myDiv').append('<table><tr><td>');
        $('#myDiv').append('<A HREF ="javascript:Data(16)">World Music</A>');
        $('#myDiv').append('</td></tr></table>');

        $('#myDiv').append('<table><tr><td>');
        $('#myDiv').append('<A HREF ="javascript:Data(17)">Relaxation</A>');
        $('#myDiv').append('</td></tr></table>');

        $('#myDiv').append('<table><tr><td>');
        $('#myDiv').append('<A HREF ="javascript:Data(18)">Malayalam</A>');
        $('#myDiv').append('</td></tr></table>');

        $('#myDiv').append('<table><tr><td>');
        $('#myDiv').append('<A HREF ="javascript:Data(19)">Tamil</A>');
        $('#myDiv').append('</td></tr></table>');

        $('#myDiv').append('<table><tr><td>');
        $('#myDiv').append('<A HREF ="javascript:Data(20)">Far East</A>');
        $('#myDiv').append('</td></tr></table>');

        $('#myDiv').append('<table><tr><td>');
        $('#myDiv').append('<A HREF ="javascript:Data(21)">Oryx Radio</A>');
        $('#myDiv').append('</td></tr></table>');

        $('#myDiv').append('<table><tr><td>');
        $('#myDiv').append('<A HREF ="javascript:Data(22)">Audio Book</A>');
        $('#myDiv').append('</td></tr></table>');

        $('#myDiv').append('<table><tr><td>');
        $('#myDiv').append('<INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Back" onClick="history.go(-1);">');

        break;

    case 2:
         alert("function 3");
        break;

 }
}

</script>
<script>


function displayData(ctr) {

switch (ctr) {

case 1:
$("a").hide();


$('#myDiv').append('<table><tr><td>');
$('#myDiv').append('<A HREF ="javascript:NextData(1)">Spotlight</A>');
$('#myDiv').append('</td></tr></table>');

$('#myDiv').append('<table><tr><td>');
$('#myDiv').append('<A HREF ="javascript:NextData(2)">Oryx highlights</A>');
$('#myDiv').append('</td></tr></table>');

$('#myDiv').append('<table><tr><td>');
$('#myDiv').append('<A HREF ="javascript:NextData(3)">Little Taster</A>');
$('#myDiv').append('</td></tr></table>');

$('#myDiv').append('<table><tr><td>');
$('#myDiv').append('<INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Back" onClick="history.go(-1);">');
 $('#myDiv').append('</td></tr></table>');
break;

case 2:
$("a").hide();


$('#myDiv').append("<table> <tr> <td>");
$('#myDiv').append('<A HREF = "#" ONCLICK="abc(1)">Spotlight</A>');
$('#myDiv').append(" </td></tr></table> ");

$('#myDiv').append("<table> <tr> <td>");
$('#myDiv').append('<A HREF = "#" ONCLICK="abc(2)">Oryx highlights</A>');
$('#myDiv').append(" </td></tr></table> ");

$('#myDiv').append("<table> <tr> <td>");
$('#myDiv').append('<A HREF = "#" ONCLICK="abc(3)">Little Taster</A>');
$('#myDiv').append(" </td></tr></table> ");


 break;
case 3:
alert("aaa");
break;

}

}


</script>

 <TABLE>


        <TR>
           <TD>

               <a onclick="displayData(1)" href="#">Broadcast Video</a>
           </TD> 
        </TR>

        <TR>
           <TD>

               <a onclick="displayData(2)" href="#">Interactive Audio</a>
           </TD> 
        </TR>

        <TR>
           <TD>

               <a onclick="displayData(3)" href="#">Interactive Movies</a>
           </TD> 
        </TR>

        <TR>
           <TD>

               <a onclick="displayData(4)" href="#">Trailers</a>
           </TD> 
        </TR>

        <TR>
           <TD>

               <a onclick="displayData(5)" href="#">Interactive Trailers</a>
           </TD> 
        </TR>

        <TR>
           <TD>

               <a onclick="displayData(6)" href="#">Interactive Shorts</a>
           </TD> 
        </TR>

        <TR>
           <TD>

               <a onclick="displayData(7)" href="#">PA</a>
           </TD> 
        </TR>

        <TR>
           <TD>

               <a onclick="displayData(8)" href="#">Young Travellers</a>
           </TD> 
        </TR>

        <TR>
           <TD>

               <a onclick="displayData(9)" href="#">MISC</a>
           </TD> 
        </TR>

        <TR>
           <TD>

               <a onclick="displayData(10)" href="#">Games</a>
           </TD> 
        </TR>



 </TABLE>

<div id="myDiv"></div>

</BODY>

</HTML>
```

The only problem i am getting here is that back button is not working. Can anyone tell me how to enable data which is hidden when back button is clicked??

Comment: As you are changing your content clientside, your browser won't think anything has changed and so it won't be in the history.  [Have a read of this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history).

Comment: Can you post your code in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), so everyone can reproduve your problem?

Comment: i edited it in my question itself u can check it from there

Comment: Plz tell what is the functioning you want with your back button .. ??

Comment: When i click on back button i should go to the previous page thats why i gave `onClick="history.go(-1);` on button click but its not working. May be i am hiding previous data thats y??

Comment: How can hidden data be shown through back button??

Comment: Did anybody get solution y back button is not working